# Issues with Python readline() when reading data from Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, window

I am attempting to use pyserial to read the data from an arduino on Windows.

```
import serial

device      = 'COM3'
baud        = 9600

with serial.Serial(device,baud, timeout = 0) as serialPort:
    while True:
        line = serialPort.readline()
        line = line.decode("utf-8")
        if line:
            print(line)
```

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  int x = 12;
  int y = 34;
  int z = 56;
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(y);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.println(z);  

}
```

The arduino Serial monitor is outputting exactly what I expect.

```
12,34,56
12,34,56
12,34,56
```

The python script on the other hand is outputting:

```
1
2,34
,56



12,
34,5
6


1
2,34
,56



12,
34,5
6
```

I have tried delaying the output from the Arduino, I have tried making a buffer in the arduino code and only output the data when the buffer was full, thinking maybe python would have time to read it correctly.

I have see numerous people on this site and others make similar code and suggest it works fine, I however cannot get coherent data from python. Anyone know my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this

Python

```
import serial

device = 'COM3'
baud = 9600

with serial.Serial(device, baud) as port:
    while True:
        print(port.readline().decode("utf-8"))
```

Arduino

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int x = 12;
  int y = 34;
  int z = 56;
  Serial.println(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);  
}
```

Comment: Fixed! Thank you! The python code and arduino code work together from this comment, however, my original python script works as well as an FYI.